# How to handle POST request to PERL from html

Tags: perl, post, cpanel

I am writing a small cPanel plugin which basically submit an html form to a perl file over ajax request to the perl file.

The type of the request is POST as I need to send some data to the script.

**My Question is how can I handle the POST data in perl?**

Now, I have found few implementations with the CGI library, however I do not have that available as default cPanel perl module. Furthermore I have found few examples with the LWP library, however I am failing to understand those. Can someone give me any suggestion on this.

Thank you!

Comment: $cgi->postdata, IIRC. Read the docs

Comment: $cgi utilized the cgi perl library which is not available in the default perl modules set of the cPanel service. I know that this is an option, however I would like to stick to the default perl modules set.

Comment: Huh? 1. CGI.pm comes with Perl. 2. Are you asking us to copy CGI.pm here?

Comment: @SimeonMitev: What makes you think that `CGI` isn't part of *“the default perl modules set”*? I see that you are calling it `cgi`, but if you `use cgi` in your program then it won't be found. It is spelled `CGI` and you need to `use CGI` for it to be found

Comment: Actually I think that I am seeing your point now, please excuse me @ikegami and thank you @Borodin!

Comment: Thank you guys for opening my eyes! I have achieved what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use CGI qw( );
my $cgi = CGI->new();
my $json = $cgi->param('POSTDATA');
```

Comment: I have marked this answer as the correct one simply because this was exactly what I was looking for, however I would like to thank @Borodin for the detailed explanation of the STDIN approach. Unfortunately that approach does not suite my needs for simple check of 3 variables I am passing with Ajax request to perl script. The variables are then checked as suggested above with the following code:

my $q = new CGI;

my $combineCSS = $q->param('combineCSS');
my $extendCache = $q->param('extendCache');

I would like to sincerely thank all of the people sparing some time for a newbie like me.

Answer (score 2):

All that you need to know is in [***RFC3875***](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3875/) — the specification for *The Common Gateway Interface Version 1.1*

Essentially, the CGI program is passed information about the incoming request message through both the environment variables and the `STDIN` input channel. If the CGI program is a Perl one then the environment variables can be accessed through the built-in hash `%ENV`, which will contain a fixed set of values such as `REQUEST_METHOD` (which will normally be `HEAD`, `GET`, or `POST`) or `CONTENT_LENGTH`

The body of the message is delivered to the CGI program via its STDIN channel, and the value of `CONTENT_LENGTH` indicates how many bytes should be read from the channel to fetch the complete message body

In the case of a `POST` message that represents form input from the browser, `REQUEST_METHOD` will, obviouly, be `POST`; `CONTENT_TYPE` will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (unless one of the form fields is a file upload); and `CONTENT_LENGTH` will hold the number of bytes of data in the request message body, which is the amount of data that the CGI program should read from `STDIN`. This should be done using `read STDIN` instead of the usual `<STDIN>` because the server may not put an EOF after the valid body data. Your code will look like

```
my $bytes_read = read STDIN, my $form_data, $ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH}
```

after which the form data will be saved in `$form_data` in the same format as the query portion of a `GET` URL (that's what the `urlencoded` part of the content type means)

If you need to know any more about what the CGI environment provides and expects then take a look at the RFC that I have linked above. It's fairly straightforward to read

Answer (score 0):

[Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30448213/1824796)'s answer says all. Basically, you don't need the CGI.pm [overhead](https://youtu.be/jKOqtRMT85s):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
use strict;
use warnings;

my %form;
if ($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq 'POST') {
    read(STDIN, my $form_data, $ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH})
      or die "$!\n";

    # URL decode
    chomp($form_data);
    $form_data =~ tr/+/ /;
    $form_data =~ s/%([a-f0-9][a-f0-9])/chr(hex($1))/egi;

    foreach (split /&/, $form_data) {
        # trim spaces
        s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

        # get the URL param
        my($key, $value) = split(/=/, $_, 2);
        $form{$key} = $value || '';
    }
}
```

a **dichotomy**

*HTML* `<input type="text" name="email" />`

*CGI* `my $email = $form{email};`

Comment: This doesn't work. It will break if the input contains any (properly-encoded) `&` or `=`.