# Gui of Perl Script

Tags: perl, command

I have a perl script that has parameters (for example) "perl script.pl (parameter 1) (parameter 2)"

And I want the script to have gui, so the user puts the two parameters in 2 textbox and then by clicking on a button, the script with those parameters is executed.

If it is not possible with visual basic, please say with what program is it possible to do that.

Comment: [`Tk`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/Tk.pod) and [`Wx`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Wx)  are the two mature GUI frameworks I'm aware of for Perl. `Tk` has its roots in Unix systems and `Wx` has roots in MSWindows.

Comment: Im not very familiar with programming, I know only a little bit of java and c++, is it somehow possible to execute a command in cmd with visual basic? Like make it open cmd with the parameters already wroten or (if nothing of that is possible) at least make it generate the command, so you just need to copy it from textbox and paste in cmd.

Comment: So this is a visual basic question, not a perl question.

Comment: @mob Note there is also [`Gtk3`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Gtk3). I tested a little bit, and it seems to work fine on my platform (Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out (somehow) how to do it in Visual Basic, and it works.
Thank you anyways, guys!

Comment: It might be helpful for future viewers if you explain what you did.

Comment: I did this @oldtechaa: `Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox3.Text = "perl process " & TextBox1.Text & " " & TextBox5.Text & " " & TextBox4.Text & " " & TextBox2.Text
    End Sub` and that generates the code in a hidden textbox and when you press other button, that executes the code in that textbox: `Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Shell("cmd.exe /k " + TextBox3.Text)
        'Shell("cmd.exe /c " + TextBox3.Text)
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

If you have your script running on a webserver you could potentially build your GUI in HTML and then pass the parameters via POST request to your script. Without some prior knowledge of programming and the http protocol it might take a bit of research to get this setup and running.

There is some more discussion about how you could potentially do this in the answers to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30448476/6194845)